# How to overload a Rust function to accept closures with different argument signatures? Blanket implementation on different closure types

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a Rust function `printf` that can accept closures with different argument signatures. The function already has two implementations - `printf1` which accepts closures with two `i32` arguments, and `printf2` which accepts closures with one `i32` argument and returns a closure that also accepts an `i32` argument. 
(I want to have a `printf` function that chooses between them depending on the input or something similar)

```
fn printf1<F>(f: F, a: i32, b: i32)
where
F: FnOnce(i32, i32) -> i32,
{
println!("Result is {result}", result = f(a, b),)
}

fn printf2<F, G>(f: F, a: i32, b: i32)
where
F: FnOnce(i32) -> G,
G: FnOnce(i32) -> i32,
{
println!("Result is {result}", result = f(a)(b),)
}
```

I tried implementing a trait `DynChainCall` to be able to add the trait as a bound to the `F` type parameter of `printf`. However, I'm not sure how to add support for closures with two `i32` arguments as well as closures that return a closure with a signature of `FnOnce(i32) -> i32`.

```
trait DynChainCall {
    fn call_print(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32;
}

impl<F> DynChainCall for F
where
    F: FnOnce(i32, i32) -> i32,
{
    fn call_print(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        self(a, b)
    }
}

impl<F, G> DynChainCall for F
where
    F: FnOnce(i32) -> G,
    G: FnOnce(i32) -> i32,
{
    fn call_print(&self, a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
        self(a)(b)
    }
}

fn printf<P: DynChainCall>(f: P, a: i32, b: i32) {
    println!("Result is {}", f.call_print(a, b));
}
```

-> `conflicting implementations of trait DynChainCall`
An example of two closures/functions that I would like to pass into `printf`:

```
fn function(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

fn func(a: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    move |b| a + b
}
```

I want `printf` to automatically check if the passed closure `f` accepts one or two arguments and call it accordingly . If the closure accepts one argument and returns a closure with a signature/closure type of `FnOnce(i32) -> i32`, then it should call `f(a)(b)`. If it returns a `i32` then it should call `f(a, b)`.

```
printf(function, 25, 10); // This should work! ( function(25, 10) is called )
printf(func, 25, 10); // This should also work! ( func(25)(10) is called )
```

How can I implement this behavior of `printf`?

Also:
I tried to somehow make a weird enum with two variants to try and do a pattern match. 
 But I stopped trying to implement this because it is super clunky *even if* it works.

```
enum Function {
    FnOnceVariant(Box<dyn FnOnce(i32, i32) -> i32>),
    FnVariant(Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>)
}
```

Comment: AIUI this can't work without specialization because, while nothing currently can implement two different `Fn*` traits, the compiler has no special knowledge of that when it comes to generic trait bounds, which means that the two impls are not seen as mutually exclusive by the compiler, even if _we_ know they are. I think you _could_ use the "deref specialization" hack, but it requires macros in order to be ergonomic.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some stuff but I can't get it to work with a `printf` function. I will use a macro for now. (In case someone needs an alternative) This is how I did it:

1. Make traits for both closure types

```
trait FunctionCall<O> {
    fn call_print(self, a: O, b: O) -> O;
}

trait FunctionComposition<O> {
    fn call_print(self, a: O, b: O) -> O;
}
```

2. Define my `printf` behaviour for both closures

```
impl<F, O> FunctionCall<O> for F
where
    F: FnOnce(O, O) -> O,
{
    fn call_print(self, a: O, b: O) -> O {
        self(a, b)
    }
}

impl<F, G, O> FunctionComposition<O> for F
where
    F: FnOnce(O) -> G,
    G: FnOnce(O) -> O,
{
    fn call_print(self, a: O, b: O) -> O {
        self(a)(b)
    }
}
```

3. Make a macro that expands to call `call_print`

```
macro_rules! printf {
    ($f:expr, $a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        println!("Result is {}", ($f).call_print($a, $b));
    };
}
```

4. Make two functions with the corresponding signatures

```
fn function(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

fn func(a: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    move |b| a + b
}
```

5. Try it out.

```
fn main() {
    printf!(function, 22, 33);
    printf!(func, 33, 44);
}
```

-> 
`Result is 55` 
`Result is 77`

Comment: Defining `printf!` as a macro is a nice solution, but doesn't strictly "*implement a Rust function `printf` that can accept closures*" as the question asked for :-)